# NetSuite - Get the internalId via SOAP/WS for department, category, currency

Tags: soap, netsuite

please tell me that there is a way to get the internal ID of a department, expense category or currency if I do not have the internalID via a webservice?

Answer (score 0):

You can view the internal id's in NetSuite when looking at the record. You can also search via webservices to find the specific record and then find the internal id. If the record is not available in a simple search you can create a saved search inside of NetSuite to pull the information and then query the saved search via web services.

Department uses the DepartmentSearch class
Expense Category uses ExpenseCategorySearch class

Currency doesn't have a search class so you will have to use the alternative methods I suggested.